Как и можно ли вообще дообучить LLM модель mistral используемую через Ollama
Я для своего голосового ассистента с ИИ использую ollama, модель mistral.
Как многие знают использовать сухую LLM модель это не лучшая идея когда нужно сделать что то конкретное.
Другими словами мне нужно дообучить эту модель, используя питон, я почитал статьи о том как дообучать модели, но как будто там не совсем то, что мне нужно.
Конечно у меня есть вариант просто написать очень много примеров диалога в промте, но это повлияет на время генерации.
Если есть те, кто разбираются в вопросе буду очень благодарен за помощь)
Могу написать какие то уточнения если нужно

как задать хороший вопрос
